# Iterating rows of dataframe by steps

Tags: python, pandas

In the following code, I want to iterate over a dataframe by 14 steps.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(index)
    batch_df = pd.DataFrame( df[index:index+14] )
    index = index + 14
```

The printed index numbers are sequential starting from 0,1,... However I expect to see 0,14,28,...

How can I fix that?

Comment: do it in groups `for index, grp in df.groupby(df.index //14)` pretty sure we can avoid the loop. What you trying to do ?

Comment: Since you specify index in your loop you overwrite the value of the index+14 line for every step in your loop. It is not really clear what you wish to achieve. Do you need the information from each row, or are you just trying to batch your dataframe into chunks of 14 rows?

Comment: I want to create batches of the original dataframe and process them in a loop. So while it hasn't reached the end of the original dataframe, reads the rows by 14 steps. So, indices should be [0:13][14:27]... and not [0:13][1:14][2:15]...

Comment: @Umar.H:  Just replacing the `for` line gives me the same result as before.

Comment: @mahmood your `print(index)` will still give `0,1,2...` *but* your `grp` is now a `DataFrame` with 14 rows (except possibly the last iteration) -- so use `for _, batch_df in df.groupby(df.index //14): <your code>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what context you provided I don't see why you need to loop through the dataframe. I think using `range(start, end, step)` will give you your desired result.

```
for i in range(0, len(df), 14):
    batch_df = df.iloc[i:i+14]
```

Comment: At batch_df line I get `ValueError: Boolean array expected for the condition, not object` error.

Comment: oops sorry. I edited the code now :)

Answer (score 0):

To translate Umar.H's comment to match your code:

```py
for _, batch_df in df.groupby(df.index//14):
    <your code>
```

**BUT** as Umar.H mentioned, whatever you're wanting to accomplish can likely (and *should*, if feasible) be accomplished without the use of a `for`-loop at all. `pandas` has a host of useful functions that may already do what you need; and even if not, a `.apply` or `.transform` allow you to use your own custom functions. For example:

```py
df['new_metric'] = df.groupby(df.index//14).transform(custom_func)
```